# Stop Google Analytics Realtime tracking on Adobe AIR app after closing?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, adobe, google-analytics

I'm using Adobe's [Google Analytics SWC](http://code.google.com/p/gaforflash/downloads/list) library for flex. What I'm trying to achieve is to simply be able to utilize the realtime features of Google Analytics to know when users have my AIR desktop application open.

Making it detect an open application was easy enough. I can visually see the count on Google Analytics getting updated in a matter of seconds whenever I open up my application. However, the problem occurs when I close my app. Google Analytics doesn't seem to detect a closed app and still detects it as open on the realtime view. How would I go with making Google Analytics know that the application has stopped?

So far, it seems the realtime counter only reverts back to 0 after some 30 or so minutes that I have already closed the app. This leads me to believe that it was considered to be idle by Google and so decided to update the statistics. That might be good and all but I really want to utilize the realtime capability so I need it to reflect when an app closes with only a few seconds of offset.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this one will work (don't know that Android will kill the process and restart it each time) but if it does it's an answer:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html#event:exiting

Also check out the Deactivate event as it seems to be relevant, more on mobile app life cycle here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f82c4ee412b1275403b-8000.html

From the Google Analytics documentation.

> setSessionTimeout ()  method    public function
>   setSessionTimeout(newTimeout:int):void
>
> Sets the new session timeout in seconds. By default, session timeout
>   is set to 30 minutes (1800 seconds).
>
> Session timeout is used to compute visits, since a visit ends after 30
>   minutes of browser inactivity or upon browser exit.
>
> If you want to change the definition of a "session" for your
>   particular needs, you can pass in the number of seconds to define a
>   new value.
>
> This will impact the Visits reports in every section where the number
>   of visits are calculated, and where visits are used in computing other
>   values.
>
> For example, the number of visits will increase if you shorten the
>   session timeout, and will decrease if you increase the session
>   timeout.

Comment: Well for one, I'm asking about desktop AIR applications (as seen on my post), and I'm looking for ways to tell Google Analytics that my AIR desktop application has already quit and that it should update the realtime counter already. I'm aware of Event.EXITING, I just don't know what code to put on there to make it talk to Google Analytics about it exiting.

Comment: @ShedoSurashu, sorry most of the recent questions on AIR lately have been related to mobile, also I figured the Google analytics part would be straight-forward since you already have it alerting when the application loads I figured un-load would be using the same communication.  From looking around I would guess you're using this but I'm not sure http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html

Comment: Also I checked out a site I have under google analytics and it seems it automatically times out the normal active visitors on site count after some period of time even if I still have the page open, also when I close the tab it doesn't reduce the number immediately.

Comment: Check in the documentation included alongside the swc, in GATracker it says you can use the set session timeout value and by default it's 30 min, adding a snippet from there up above.

Comment: Brilliant! I never thought of it that way! Good call man. I'm currently trying it out, in the mean time, do you think there is a limit to the number of seconds I can set? I was thinking of maybe setting the initial timeout to some absurd count like 1 day then, on exit, I'll set the timeout to 1 second. Would that possibly work?

Comment: Hmm, setting the timeout seems to still yield the same results. I tried setting the timeout to 1 and 5 seconds respectively just to try and it didn't seem to affect the realtime counter.

Comment: Sorry was sort of a shot in the dark, if I have some time anytime soon I'll give the whole analytics thing a shot myself (been playing with some mobile game development).  Till I get my hands deeper in it I don't think anything else I suggest will help, best of luck.